# Python: Make Virtual Assistant Listen Again After Saying "Hey Assistant"

Tags: python, speech-recognition

Using the code below the virtual assistant will listen for commands but after saying "try again" it will stop to listen. How do I make it listen again using the wake command "hey assistant".

```
def myCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()                                                                                   
    with sr.Microphone() as source:                                                                       
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold =  1
        text = r.listen(source)
    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(text, language='en')
        print('User: ' + query + '\n')

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        speak('Sorry sir! I didn\'t get that.')
        query = str(input('Try again'))




    return query
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# you can call it using this...
hotword = 'hey assistant'
while 1:
    result = myCommand()
    if hotword in result:
        #here what you want to do...
        #respose_of_assistant()
```